# How to free memory in PHP or improve PHPExcel?

Tags: php, algorithm, memory, garbage-collection, phpexcel

[PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) need too much memory to load file. I want improve this code by memory usage.

It breaks with error `Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted` on this code:

```
/* class PHPExcel_Cell 
 *
 * $returnValue = array()
 * 
*/

$sortKeys = array();

foreach (array_unique($returnValue) as $coord) {
    sscanf($coord,'%[A-Z]%d', $column, $row);
        $sortKeys[sprintf('%3s%09d',$column,$row)] = $coord;
}

ksort($sortKeys);

return array_values($sortKeys);
```

> $returnValue = array("B1", "C12", "C1", "D3", "B2"...) 
>   
>  must be sorted like array("B1", "B2", "C1", "C12")

**First problem:** If I understand correctly, **array_unique** use one additional array to store result, so total memory usage **x2** (if we have array with unique elements). But I think not need to use array_unique, because any duplicates will be rewritten with this line:

```
$sortKeys[sprintf('%3s%09d',$column,$row)] = $coord;
```

**Second Problem:** This code use two arrays: $returnValue and $sortKeys (2x memory), so I rewrote it like:

```
$len = count($returnValue);

for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {

    $val = $returnValue[$i];
    unset($returnValue[$i]);

    sscanf($val,'%[A-Z]%d', $column, $row);
    $returnValue[sprintf('%3s%09d',$column,$row)] = $val;

}

ksort($returnValue);

return array_values($returnValue);
```

But **unset()** doesn't free memory, only removed element from array and **gc_collect_cycles()** also not working.

How can I free memory after **unset**?
Maybe you know other way, how improve this code by memory usage?

P.S. I can not use **xlsx2csv** and other bash tools.

Comment: You can try using Spout instead (https://github.com/box/spout). It has less features than PHPExcel but is really good at performance and memory usage (you won't need more than 10MB!).

Comment: @Adrien - `How to improve PHPExcel` doesn't mean `how to switch to an alternative`.... I'm interested in answers on how to improve PHPExcel myself.... and as spout doesn't care about user's running PHP < 5.4 there's a whole host of things that it can do differently and more efficiently than PHPExcel

Comment: I mentioned Spout because the original question already mentioned alternatives (xlsx2csv) so I thought it was appropriate. The way I understand the problem here is less about how to improve PHPExcel's gc but more about how can I get my work done. Feel free to delete my comment if you find it inappropriate and please accept my apologies :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks pretty strange, you remove element from array and then add a new one in one loop.
When I used PHPExcel i used destructors to free memory and it worked very well

```
function __destruct()
    {
        if ($this->phpExcelObj) {
            \PHPExcel_Calculation::unsetInstance($this->phpExcelObj);
            if ($this->phpExcelObj) {
                $this->phpExcelObj->disconnectWorksheets();
                unset($this->phpExcelObj);
            }
        }
    }
```

The other way is to make templates with Word and load that template with PHPExcel, then you will avoid using memory consumption operations for making markup of your document.
These techniques helped me to load million of rows using PHPExcel with not so much memory.

Comment: It breaks on the first load, so destructor cannot help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it helps, but You could try this:

```
$spreadsheet->disconnectWorksheets();
unset($spreadsheet);
```

from: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/creating-spreadsheet/#clearing-a-workbook-from-memory